# Change in vapour pressure due to climate change

Tags: climate-change, climate, water, water-vapour

I was just wondering how much the vapour pressure has changed due to climate change. Because with changing temperatures, the vapour pressure also changes; this is described by the Clausius-Clapeyron equation. Does anyone have a suitable paper on how this has changed in the Northern hemisphere?

Comment: Do you mean relative humidity ?

Comment: Relative humidity is going to be significantly different than vapor pressure as a question... relative humidity changes based on air temperature without any change in actual underlying atmospheric moisture amounts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could Global Climate Change increase the average moisture in the air?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/9238/could-global-climate-change-increase-the-average-moisture-in-the-air)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. The linked question asks about potential changes *in the future*, thus an answer would rely on models, while this question asks about changes *in the (recent) past*, thus an answer would rely on actual measures.

Comment: @Jean-MariePrival good point

Comment: You might find the [global desertification](https://ddebernardy.substack.com/p/global-desertification) chapter of my book interesting. It discusses water vapor and where the recent increase (see NASA data) might be coming from.